# Describing all integral submanifolds of a distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Definition:

> Suppose $D \subset TM$ is a smooth distribution of rank $k$. An embedded submanifold $S^{k} \subset M$ is called an integral submanifold of $D$ if $$T_p S=D_p \quad \forall p \in S.$$

My problem is:

> Consider the smooth vector fields \begin{equation}
> X:=z\partial_y+y\partial_z, \quad Y:=-x\partial_z-z\partial_x \quad \mbox{e}\quad Z:=y\partial_x-x\partial_y\end{equation} in $M:=\mathbb{R}^{3}-\{0\}$.Describe all integral submanifolds of the distribution $$D=\langle X,Y, Z \rangle \quad \mbox{(spanned by the vector fields)}.$$

I checked that $D$ is an involutive distribution of rank $2$. However I don't know how to describe all integral submanifolds of $D$. How can I do this?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Is $M = \mathbb R^3$? It seems that $D$ is not a smooth distribution of any rank. If has rank $0$ at the origin, and rank $3$ when $xyz \neq 0$.

Comment: The only problem is at the origin ... at every point $xX+yY+zZ=0$, so the distribution is indeed of rank 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, this can be a very hard question. However, in this particular case, as it is of rank 2, you could try and find a differential $1$-form whose kernel coincides with $D_p$ at every point. Quite easily, if you set $\omega=a(x,y,z)dx+b(x,y,z)dy+c(x,y,z)dz$ and ask that $\omega(X)=\omega(Y)=\omega(Z)=0$, you get the conditions
$$zb+yc=0\qquad -xc-za=0\qquad ya-xb=0$$
which implies that $a(x,y,z)=xh(x,y,z)$, $b(x,y,z)=yh(x,y,z)$, $c(x,y,z)=-zh(x,y,z)$ for some function $h(x,y,z)$. Therefore, we obtain an ideal (as we expect!) which is principal and generated by $\omega_0=xdx+ydy-zdz$.

So, we have a differential $1$-form such that $D_p=\ker(\omega_0)\vert_p$ for every $p\in\mathbb{R}^3$. As we know that $D$ is involutive, we expect to find a potential for $\omega_0$ and indeed $2\omega_0=d(x^2+y^2-z^2)$.

So, the level sets of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$ are the integral submanifolds of $D$.

Comment: Yea! Forms for the win, again :)

Comment: Obviously! How else? ;)

Comment: I've answered three or four such Frobenius questions and used that refrain :)

Comment: It is actually an embodiment of the equivalent of Frobenius theorem for ideals of differential forms, or at least that would be the only reason to give such an exercise...to actually show how to change from vectorfields to forms and back.